# Hover on div triggered by parent span

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseover

I have a sprite icon that animates when the div it's in is mouseover'd. 
That icon is currently in a `<span>` card.

I'd like the icon to animate when I hover over the `<span>` and not just when it's over the icon. Is there any way of doing this?

Here's a codepen link to what I'm dealing with.
http://codepen.io/phantomboogie/pen/bwgNwq

Here's the html and js

```
<span class="card">
<div class="icon book"></div>
</span>

<script>
var timer;
$(".book").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('sprite_animating');
}) .mouseleave(function(){
    }) .on('animationend', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('sprite_animating');});
</script>
```

Comment: Snippet link fail

Comment: First, stop producing invalid HTML - you can not put a DIV into a SPAN.

Answer (score 0):

You would just have to target the parent `<div>`. If parent has class`.card` you would target it.

```
$(".card").mouseenter(function(){
    $(.book).toggleClass('sprite_animating');
})
```

Change the `this` in the function to the class you wish to add the "toggleClass" class to.

It would be the same thing for the `mouseleave()` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could actually do this with only CSS and no javascript at all (since you're using CSS3 animation) with this CSS rule

```
.card:hover .icon{animation: sprite-flip 1s steps(59) 1 forwards ;}
```

I added the `forwards` so that `.icon` stay in the end position of the animation